# Sql group by dates and then find avg

Tags: sql, date, group-by, wildcard, average

I have a database, including the field "Date" of the form e.g. "2012-06-13 23:34:52+00" and the field "Sentiment", including a double signed value between -1 and 1. What I want is to calculate the average sentiment, grouped by each hour of the day. For example, I would like to have as a result the following table:

```
Hour......Average Sentiment   
00 .........  0.5  
01 ......... -0.2  
...  
24 .........  0.7
```

I guess I'll have to use group by, the avg function and probably some wildcards to extract the hour from "Date". If someone is more experienced, please help me find the most efficient way of querying this.

Thank you.

Comment: The name of your dbms (mysql, sql server...) would help. The type of your Date field also.

Comment: I currently have this on Google Docs as a spreadsheet and I'm planning on querying it using the Google js API. The "Data" field is of Text format. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know Google spreadsheet should be used as a db, and Google js API as an "SQL language". See my edit then.

Answer (score 1):

Answer should be better if I knew your DBMS. `<functionToGetHour>` will depend on your DBMS.

AVG is (if i'm not wrong) ANSI SQL.

The idea is something like that.

If you want a result for every hour even if there's no "Sentiment" for that hour, it's possible, but little bit more complicated.

```
SELECT t1.<functionToGetHour>(Date), AVG(t1.Sentiment)
FROM <YOURTABLE> t1
GROUP BY t1.<functionToGetHour>(Date)
```

**EDIT**

With Google API (if we're talking about https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=fr )

```
select hour(datetime  `Date`), avg(sentiment) group by hour(datetime  `Date`)
```

date is a reserved keyword, so it's a rather bad idea to use it as a field. Don't know is google API is case sensitive...

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(date_field, 'YYYY MM DD HH'), average(sentiment) # to_char= oracle
from sentimemt_table
group by to_char(date_field, 'YYYY MM DD HH')

# mySQL: DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%Y %M %D %H') instead of to_char
# Postgres: to_char(date_field, 'YYYY:MM:DD:HH24')
# SQLServer: CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), date_field(), 120)
```